# Как узнать открыт ли определенный сайт в браузере в данное время?

Tags: python

Пишу программу в питоне которая подскажет какой сайт открыт. Скажите как узнать открыт ли сайт в данное время?

Comment: Нужно искать окно браузера, в нем адресную строку, забирать оттуда текст и искать в нем имя хоста, но последнее - самое простое.

Comment: А можно ли это через python реализовать а не вручную?

Comment: Можно и через Питон, но вручную.

Comment: как делается в питоне не подскажете?

Comment: Подсказано в первом комментарии.

Comment: какой контекст у задачи? Перебирать окошки на десктопе в поиска браузера, пытаться искать строки в GUI элементах — это хрупко, вероятно окольно.

Comment: при открытие сайта данные передается на сайт, думаю что можно узнать куда т,е на какой сайт передается эти данные со средствами питон

Comment: @MeirbekBolatbekov почему именно средствами Питон? В инструментах разработчика в браузере можно посмотреть сетевые соединения

Comment: как получить эти данные оттуда на мою программу